# How to list .txt files with specific content?

Tags: linux, files, grep, find, search

How do I list all .txt files with their full path that have a word 'Ubuntu' in them. Ignore non-text files. When comparing values you should ignore the case i.e. UBUNTU or ubuNtu or UbUnTu are treated as equal to the search phrase given.

Answer (score 10):

GNU grep supports recursive searching based on a glob-pattern, e.g.:

```
grep --include='*.txt' -ril ubuntu /path/to/dir
```

If you are not searching for a regular expression, this process will be much faster if you include fixed-string matching (`-F`). Another optimization is to remove ignore-case (`-i`) if you know it is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Simple **`find`** + **`grep`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -li --binary-files=without-match 'ubuntu' {} \;
```

`grep` details:

- `l` - suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed
- `i` - ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in case match each other

Comment: as OP stated, it should return full path, so you need to have `/path/to` as path to search or `$PWD` from current directory instead

Comment: If I want to search for all text files(.log etc) and not necessarily only .txt files, what should be the command

Comment: @SampadMund, just remove `-name "*.txt"` from the command

Answer (score 3):

Some implementation of the `grep` utility has an `-I` flag that makes `grep` ignore binary files.  You may also use `-i` to do a case-insensitive match and `-F` to match with a fixed string (rather than with a regular expression).  If you are looking for separate *words* you will want to use `-w` that some `grep` implementations has. Then, to recurse into subdirectories, you may want to use `-R` to recursively search files and `-l` to get the names of the files that contains matches of the pattern. Then we'd like to use `--include` if we have GNU `grep` to only look at files with a certain extension.

```
grep -Fil -IRw --include='*.txt' 'ubuntu' /path/to/top/dir
```

Standard options used: `-F`, `-i`, `-l`.

Non-standard options used (supported by some `grep` implementations): `-w`, `-I`, `-R`, `--include`.

---

Using `find` and OpenBSD `grep` which does not have `--include` and which uses `--binary-files` instead of `-I` (GNU `grep` also has this flag):

```
find /path/to/top/dir -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -exec grep -Fil -w --binary-files=without-match 'ubuntu' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I typically use:

```
find /path/to/top/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep -iHI ubuntu {} \;
```

Comment: If I want to search for all text files(.log etc) and not necessarily only .txt files, what should be the command?